# Changing the style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm still a LaTeX beginner. I'm using kile and KBibTeX on lubuntu. I try to use `biblatex`. I copied this from a help document into my preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\bibliography{Quellen}
```

"Quellen" is the name of my KBibTeX document.

It works like that even if after running BibTeX, LaTeX says

`finished with exit code 2`.

When I try to change the style e.g. to apalike by writing

```
\usepackage[style=apalike]{biblatex}
```

LaTeX says `package 'apalike' not found\RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}`.

I already tried to download the `apalike.sty` and `apalike.bst` and put it the  same folder as the LaTeX document, but it doesn't work.
I although checked all of the entries in the KBibTeX file. There is no error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Which version of `biblatex` do you have? With recent versions, you need to give `backend=bibtex` as one of the load-time options, as the default back end is now `biber`.

Comment: I use biblatex (1.7-1). what are load-time options?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example.  From your comments, it sounds like you are mixing traditional BibTeX commands with those required by `biblatex`.  Start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is kind of a mixing there.

If you want to use `Bibtex` and `apalike` style, it's enough with writing:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Quellen}
```

I would also suggest to use the `natbib` package along:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

However, if you want to use `Biblatex`, I recommend using `Biber` to handle your references.

You could take a look at this question for more information:

[bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

[What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex/5095#5095)

Comment: I tried \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Quellen}

Comment: but than latex says "missing 'biblatex' package.{}" than I tried to put in \usepackage{biblatex} than latex says "\bibliographystyle 'invalid' \bibliographystyle{apasoft}" and in the pdf-file the plain style will appear. and i dont understand what biber is. how do you use it?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105/27833, it might clarify your doubts.  Also, if you could add a (MWE)[http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/27833] the community will be able to help you best.

Comment: I think a got it know. I can not use apalike in biblatex. rigth? I konw use the authoryear style with biblatex. that works

Answer (score 1):

It may sound daft, but I just wonder if the filename database has been updated by running `texhash` after adding the package (manually, I guess).

Comment: i don't understand. how can update? I once did the with another package and there it worked without updating.

Comment: @Frida  Missed that you're using Linux, my bet! In Linux, 'initexmf' is unlikely to exist and the syntax of 'texhash' for Linux may differ from that of Windows. So, I've just corrected my suggestion. For the correct syntax, check [link](http://http://manpages.ubuntu.com/).  For being sure the needed packages are installed, check out Thorsten's comment @ [link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=15173). For an overview of manually installing packages, check out [link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/tips-customstyles.html).

Comment: For those in windows with TexLive, just open **Tex Live Manager** and click on *Actions* menu then select *Update filename database*